# Python code can't compile on RPi (missing lib-old folder)

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors

I did a small python project on RPi but I am still noob in this environment so if you can please help me..

When I run my code with the command "python test.py" everything works OK, but when I try to compile it, it fails to find a certain folder, lib-old. I dont know why is it even searching for that folder?
This is what I write:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/kt_wishes $ python -m compileall
Skipping current directory
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7 ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old ...
Can't list /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload ...
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0 ...
```

I am compiling because I need to make script so the application starts on startup. If I can place the .py file in the script instead of the compiled, I wont even try to compile it at all.

Just to mention, the project I am trying to compile is in the folder that I am actaully in (kt_wishes).

Sorry if I am missing something out, I am really noob in this matter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a scripting language and thus interpreter (or in some expressions bytecode or hybrid) and not compiler based. I dont see any need nor application of complation here. In order to run saved Python Scripts during startup there are quite a few quick and easy ways to do so. Here are five of them: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Hope this helps,
Lars